# Does any square matrix has a invertible matrix squence converging to it?

Tags: matrices, analysis

For a square matrix $A$(may be not invertible), does there exist a invertible matrix sequence $\{A_k\}$ which satisifys $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}A_k=A$? How to prove it?

Answer (score 7):

There are finitely many $\lambda$ such that $(A-\lambda I)$ is not invertible, so for $n\ge N_0$ the sequence $A - \frac{1}{n}I$ consists of invertible matrices, and converges to $A$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!